# Displaying aws S3 objects with Python Flask

Tags: python, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

For a while I have been building a program that decompiles Adobe flash .swf files.

I have stored them in aws s3, and have keys stored in a local file that helps me locate them. Essentially I am using them as a database of sorts.

An example of the keys I have are:

```
amazon.com/none/0a5a87af2555f32c5ab9f6b7e7a14135.swf/300/250/100/2014/06/26/14/21/13images118.JPG
amazon.com/none/0a5a87af2555f32c5ab9f6b7e7a14135.swf/300/250/100/2014/06/26/14/21/13images133.JPG
```

In the above case these are jpg files that are stored.
I search through my keys and find those that I want. For example I might want an ad hosted on amazon that is a jpg.

When I run something like this in my Api Flask file:

```
@app.route('/getToday', methods=['GET'])
def getToday():
    #TODO
    return jsonify(accessS3.getDecompiledTodayFromFile())
    return "Getting ads found today"
```

I would like to have the page .../getToday to display each object.

I have the following types of files:
.as (actionscript)
.svg 
.swf
.jpg

I would like them to each render correctly. I assume I may need to check each key and then display each type differently. So when I go to .../getToday I would like to see all of the objects in a visual form.

When I am using jsonify I am getting the following error: ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

But what can I use that isn't jsonify (just text) to see the images render?

Comment: Is the intention to display them in a browser?

Comment: yes, the intention is to display the objects